# how to get key value pair from body object in javascript while using request module

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating an application in which I want to use some data from a JSON, which is generated by another js file. Here is the code which is generating JSON

```js
var request = require('request');

module.exports = {
foo:
request('https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/c1d1e5d6-fe5c-42de-8713-60f272a3b63e?subscription-key=d3d3e4dfa8744be9b4ae47558df8fc5a&timezoneOffset=0&verbose=true&q=hey',function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred 
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received 
  console.log(body);
})
};
```

I am interested in body object, which is giving following contents -

```js
{
  "query": "hey",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Help",
    "score": 0.500165462
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Help",
      "score": 0.500165462
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.10364107
    },
    {
      "intent": "SearchHotels",
      "score": 0.00249445555
    },
    {
      "intent": "ShowHotelsReviews",
      "score": 9.451727E-06
    }
  ],
  "entities": []
}
```

Now I want to access value of intent from topScoringIntent element. That to in another JS file. I tried using body[1].intend but it gives undefined.
I am very new to javascript and need very basic code to do this. Please give some suggestions on this. Also plz tell me if this can be solved by body-parser and if yes then how?

Update - Here is the code where I want to use body['topScoringIntent'].intent as global.

```js
require('dotenv-extended').load();

var builder = require('botbuilder');
var restify = require('restify');
var Store = require('./store');
var spellService = require('./spell-service');
var request = require('request');
var myJSON = require("JSON");
var fs = require('fs');
//var window = window;
var request = require("request");
var myJSON = require("JSON");

var globalVar = [];

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();

server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});
// Create connector and listen for messages
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());



function getMyBody(url, callback) {
  request({
    url: 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/c1d1e5d6-fe5c-42de-8713-60f272a3b63e?subscription-key=d3d3e4dfa8744be9b4ae47558df8fc5a&timezoneOffset=0&verbose=true&q=hey',
    json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
      return callback(error || {statusCode: response.statusCode});
    }

    global.topScoringIntent = body['topScoringIntent'].intent;
    //if(body['topScoringIntent'].intent == 'Help');
    //console.log('yay');
    callback(null, body);  
  });

}

getMyBody('https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/c1d1e5d6-fe5c-42de-8713-60f272a3b63e?subscription-key=d3d3e4dfa8744be9b4ae47558df8fc5a&timezoneOffset=0&verbose=true&q=hey', function(err, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } 
})

if(body['topScoringIntent'].intent == 'Help');
    console.log('success');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
console.log(response.topScoringIntent.intent);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with body.[topScoringIntent].intent and its working. Now do you have some idea, how can I use it globally? can I assign it to some global variable? If you know please tell me how can I do this. Because I tried it with window.myvar = myvar but it was throwing error.

Comment: I Would rather create a global object and assign this variable has a property, see below.
//////////////////////// first create a object
"var globalVar = [];"
////////////////////////second create the variable
///////////////////////in your case
"global.topScoringIntent = body.[topScoringIntent].intent"

////////////////////////////
and any place you want, you can just call "global.topScoringIntent"

Comment: I tried your thing but its not working. I think the problem is, I am trying to assign a value (global.topScoringIntent = body.[topScoringIntent].intent) from a asynchronous function. So when I am using this global.topScoringIntent outside the function, it is executing before exexution of the function itself. Please correct if I am wrong and it its correct then could you suggest to make this function synchronous or any other alternative to do so?

Comment: Yes, in that case, then you may need to use jquery.deffered (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) and wait for a promise to move forward. If you require further assistance, its easy if you can share your code for my to guide you.

Comment: please refer this article, it will explain on how you will need to use promises
https://developer.ibm.com/node/2016/08/24/promises-in-node-js-an-alternative-to-callbacks/

in short use, promise.then to resolve this issue

Answer (score -1):

`body.topScoringIntent.intent` will return 'Help'.

To use it globally you can set a var :

```
var body = {
  "query": "hey",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Help",
    "score": 0.500165462
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Help",
      "score": 0.500165462
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.10364107
    },
    {
      "intent": "SearchHotels",
      "score": 0.00249445555
    },
    {
      "intent": "ShowHotelsReviews",
      "score": 9.451727E-06
    }
  ],
  "entities": []
}

var result = body.topScoringIntent.intent;
```

And then use result somewhere else :

```
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. thought it was answering his question. thanks for clarification.